# How to set value of TimeField in extjs 4

Tags: extjs

I have tried `setValue( Time )` which sets the display, but when we get this time then its returns `'null'("shiftTimearray.StartTime = null")`.

I'm using Ext.Version 4.2.1.

Here is my code where we are getting null even we have set Time in timefiled:

```
`shiftTimearray.StartTime = Ext.getCmp('startTime').getValue();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any further context/code, I can't reproduce your issue.  Take a look at this [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1sjj).  Maybe you're not using the Date object as the value you're passing into setValue?  According to the [API](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.6/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Time-method-setValue), the value passed in must be an object, and looking at the [source](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.6/source/Time3.html#Ext-form-field-Time-method-setValue), the code checks to see if it's a date.  Hope that helps.